# How to get the value of the area under the curve in Javascript using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, area, curve

I want to know if there is a easy way to get the value of the area of the curve that I plot using Chart.js.

I know that I can use a line chart and fill the area under the curve ["line chart with fill option"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NUqH.png)

I just want to know if I can get the value of that area without calculating the integral. Thanks!

Comment: please write the answer below if you got it